# php: how to make a method inside a class run?

Tags: php, oop, methods, execute

I started learning oop php and I don't understand how to make a method inside a class execute.
This is the code:

```
class GrabData {
public $tables=array();
public $columns=array();
public $argList;


function __construct(){
    $this->argList=func_get_args();
    $pattern;
    var_dump($this->argList);
    if(!empty($this->argList)){

        foreach($this->argList as $value){
            if(preg_match("/.+_data/",$value,$matches)){
                if(!in_array($matches[0],$this->tables)){
                    array_push($this->tables,$matches[0]);
                    var_dump($this->tables);
                }
                $pattern="/". $matches[0] . "_" . "/";
                array_push($this->columns,preg_replace($pattern,"",$value));
                var_dump($this->columns);
            }

        }
    }
}

public function gen_query(){
    var_dump($this->argList);
    echo "haha";
}

    gen_query();
}

new GrabData("apt_data_aptname");
```

Now, the `__construct` function runs when I make a new GrabData object, but the `gen_query` function doesnt execute. How do I make it execute it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to have the `gen_query` function run when the class is initiated, you could link to it in the bottom of your constructor, like so:

```
function __construct() {
    // Do your stuff here and then...
    $this->gen_query();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you assign the object returned by the `new` operator to a variable - then use that variable to execute methods on your object:

```
class GrabData {
    public $tables=array();
    public $columns=array();
    public $argList;

    function __construct() {
        $this->argList=func_get_args();
        $pattern;
        var_dump($this->argList);
        if(!empty($this->argList)){
            foreach($this->argList as $value){
                if(preg_match("/.+_data/",$value,$matches)){
                    if(!in_array($matches[0],$this->tables)){
                        array_push($this->tables,$matches[0]);
                        var_dump($this->tables);
                    }
                    $pattern="/". $matches[0] . "_" . "/";
                    array_push($this->columns,preg_replace($pattern,"",$value));
                    var_dump($this->columns);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public function gen_query() {
        var_dump($this->argList);
        echo "haha";
    }
}

$super_object = new GrabData("apt_data_aptname");
$super_object->gen_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

A different way to run a class function without initiating the class is to use the double colon scope resolution operator, strangely called "Paamayim Nekudotayim".

```
GrabData::gen_query();
```

You can read up on it [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

Comment: Didn't know of the Paamayim Nekudotayim name.

Comment: For a function that makes use of `$this`?